# Different count results in PivotTable based on 0-values in database

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A                  B              C 
                  Sent Quantity      Returned Products
1  Product A             500              0
2  Product A             400            300
3  Product A             600            400
4  Product B             250              0
5  Product B             300            150
6  Product C             700              0
```

The table shows the sent quantity (**Column B**) and returned quantity (**Column C**) of each sale (order) of a product (**Column A**).

I created a simply PivotTable based on this data which gives me the following result:

```
            Count of Sent Quantity       Count of Returned Quantity
Product A          3                             3
Product B          2                             2
Product C          1                             1
```

As you can see it counts all sales (orders) of the product no matter if there is a 0-Return.

Now I want to achieve that sales which have no returns (*0-Value in Column C*) are **EXCLUDED** from the **Count of Returned Quantity** but it should still be **INCLUDED** in the **Count of Sent Quantity**. Therefore, my desired result would be the following:

```
            Count of Sent Quantity       Count of Returned Quantity
Product A          3                             2
Product B          2                             1
Product C          1                             0
```

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter 0-values in PivotTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500860/filter-0-values-in-pivottable)

Answer (score 0):

You need  to insert  Calculated field in your pivot  which says if Returned Products>0 then 1 else o

and  at pivot use  sum and  not count  for this Field

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  It just returns a 0 or a 1, and doesn't sum the numbers.

Comment: The result of this solution in column "Count of Returned Quantity" is "1 1 0" so it refers to every sale only with 1 or 0 but does not make the 2 for example for Product A.

Comment: You can add a new column to  your spreadsheet (let's say Column D).
In that   set  a formula like 
if(c1>0,1,0)
Then you can use   Sum  in your  pivot  using D column which will give you the result.